# Update one field for all records?

Tags: delphi

I have a DBGrid coupled to an ADOQuery using a SELECT statement.

I want to update one field for all records. For example, when I enter some data in a textbox, the Field "Name" (just an example) of all records would be changed.

Comment: My advise to you is to elaborate your questions.  It's desired you put a better effort to describe your situation, including all the things that matter for a specific problem.  In this case, things like the nature of the select (some select result sets are read only at database level) and if you want to do it at the database or using this same ADOQuery component.  If you want people to invest (or waste) some time trying to help you, better if you invest some time trying to make this people understand your situation at the first place.

Answer (score 5):

for this purpose you can fire a query.

"UPDATE table SET name=textBox.text";
follow syntax of according to you. simply change that field without any where clause will change your all enteries.

Comment: dear, I said my Adoquery is select command and dbgrid shows me that table and this select may be join of some tables (not just one table)

Comment: @micheal, you didn't say the select is a join of multiple tables but that asside, Isha is correct. You could perform an update and refresh your grid after that.

Comment: Even if you have joined tables the field will come from one only. A more complex situation would be if that field would come from a UNION.

Comment: SQL with code like `name=textBox.text` looks like an invitation to SQL injection to me ;)

Comment: lol, true. OP should use parametrized queries if he decides to use this route.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL UPDATE statement to update all those records at once.

If you do not want to (or cannot) use a SQL UPDATE for any reason, and want to do the update using ADO recordset, you can write a code like this:

```
var
  AField : TField;
begin
  Assert(AdoQuery1.Active, 'Dataset is not active!');
  try
    AdoQuery1.DisableControls;
    AField := AdoQuery1.FieldByName('MyFieldName');
    AdoQuery1.First;
    while not AdoQuery1.Eof do
    begin
      AdoQuery1.Edit;
      AField.Value := Edit1.Text;
      AdoQuery1.Post;
      AdoQuery1.Next;
    end;
  finally
    AdoQuery1.EnableControls;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Please put the FieldByName out of the loop. Store the reference in a local Field object then use it in the loop. I'm sick of seeing this time and again creeping up in production code.

Comment: @Francois, yes, using FieldByName in a loop has performance drawback, but this is not a production code, I just wrote it fast to give him an idea how he can iterate over the records. Anyways, I changed it to reflect your request too.

Comment: Thanks. You cannot imagine how many times I have seen this in production code, initially from nuggets harvested here or there, but left nevertheless...